# IE 8 jQuery get not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-8, get, request

I have some problems to get a response from a get call with jQuery in IE 8. In IE 9(and I think it was IE 7, too) and other browsers it works fine. Here my Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //Hide the Animation
    $('#wait_generator').hide();
    //If an element is being selected, run the function
    $('#generator').change(function(){
        //Display the animation
        $('#wait_generator').show();
        //GET - Request at get_process.php
        //get_process simply returns a new dropdown window
        $('#result_generator').hide(); //Hide results at first
        $.get("get_process.php", {
            //Variable 'func' set to generator
            func: "generator",
            //Variable selected
            selected: $('#generator').val()
        }, 
        //GET - Response from PHP
        function(response){
            $('#result_generator').fadeOut();
            setTimeout("finishAjax_generator('result_generator', '"+escape(response)+"')", 400);
        })//End of GET Request;
        return false;
    });
});

//Displays the result
function finishAjax_generator(id, response) {
    $('#wait_generator').hide();
    $('#result_software').hide();
    $('#'+id).html(unescape(response));
    $('#'+id).fadeIn();
}
```

With debugging I found that IE 8 does not even run the "function" (or whole get) code after JSON notation. I tried with absolute url and other jQuery versions and changing .php files and and and...
Please anyone, help me to find any solution.

Comment: Don't pass code like this to `setTimeout`, use `setTimeout(function(){fini...`.

Comment: can you please add jsfiddle ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing:

```
setTimeout("finishAjax_generator('result_generator', '"+escape(response)+"')", 400);
```

to

```
setTimeout(function() {
  finishAjax_generator('result_generator', escape(response));
}, 400);
```

Comment: But there is an extra problem I found. If the browser is not in the compatibility mode, it works great, but if it is in this mode nothing works. And on some systems it just not helps to switch the mode. Can someone help?